# What are the pros/cons to these two styles of authoritative name servers

Tags: dns

Looking at the name `www.google.com`:

1. The root DNS servers tell you that `com` is managed by `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m}.gtld-servers.net`.
2. `a.gtld-servers.net` tell you that `google.com` is managed by `ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com`.
3. `ns1.google.com` tells you it's authoritative for `google.com` and tells you what `www` is.

Looking at the name `www.namecheap.com`:

1. The root DNS servers tell you that `com` is managed by `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m}.gtld-servers.net`.
2. `a.gtld-servers.net` tell you that `namecheap.com` is managed by `a{1,2,3}.verisigndns.com`.
3. `a1.verisigndns.com.` tells you it's authoritative for `namecheap.com` and tells you what `www` is.

There's a distinct difference between these two strategies. In the case of Google, the `com` DNS servers give an additional info section containing the address of `ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com`. Without that hint it'd be impossible to finish resolving as to find `ns1.google.com` you'd need to ask `ns1.google.com`. I've heard these referred to as "glue records".

When I look at the management portal for a domain registered via Namecheap there's no way for me to input these glue records. I'd have to buy a whole other domain (and let Namecheap manage DNS for it) solely so I could use it to manage the DNS for the first domain.

Is Google's way or Namecheap's way the "canonical" strategy? Are there reasons why one organization would chose to do it one way or the other? Is there an official term for these "glue records"?

Comment: Sure they allow this. I'd be very surprised if a registrar didn't. https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/768/10/how-do-i-register-personal-nameservers-for-my-domain

Comment: Your list of steps is slightly wrong: without QNAME minimization, at each step, each authoritative nameserver gets queried for the full name, and it defines itself where the zone cut is and what it should reply. And the official public name of glue records is indeed glue records, and the official technical term is "in-bailiwick nameservers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I look at the management portal for a domain registered via Namecheap there's no way for me to input these glue records.

As @grawity points out, you can add entries for your own [personal nameservers](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/768/10/how-do-i-register-personal-nameservers-for-my-domain) under the Advanced DNS settings, which allow you to specify an IP address for those servers.

[image: namecheap-glue-records]

> Is Google's way or Namecheap's way the "canonical" strategy?

I would say that Google's way is (arguably) more common but each achieves different goals.

> Are there reasons why one organization would chose to do it one way or the other?

If you have a single domain (or very few) and don't mind managing DNS yourself, Google's way is probably not bad. If you have a large number of domains, need ease of updating records, or do not want to host DNS yourself, the Namecheap way is a likely path to choose.

> Is there an official term for these "glue records"?

I am pretty certain they are just considered normal [NS Resource Records](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/ns.html).

> I'd have to buy a whole other domain (and let Namecheap manage DNS for it) solely so I could use it to manage the DNS for the first domain.

This actually works very well depending on needs.

Comment: Turns out name cheap does allow this. They have three different places on two different tabs in their UI where DNS related settings can be controlled.  None of them are labeled very well and their support staff were not very helpful as they didn't even know that the Google style was possible.